# Reporting Android Application Crashes

Tags: android

I've noticed a couple of Android applications that seem to be using a 3rd party crash reporting tool. Has anyone seen this screen and do you know where I can find it? I started using http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/ but i rather not require internet permissions if I can use an intent to send emails.

[alt text http://img532.yfrog.com/img532/808/devicefeedback.png](http://img532.yfrog.com/img532/808/devicefeedback.png)

Comment: Indeed, sending a report mail would not require the internet permission. But sending mails makes the error reports _NOT_ anonymous! As their email address will show up.

Comment: I have implemented the other solutions already. So, the point of the question is to locate this library. I'm looking for answers, not opinions. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming release of Android "Froyo" will include a new bug reporting feature for Market apps. Developers will receive crash and freeze reports from their users. The reports will be available when they log into their Android Market publisher account. No more blind debugging!

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html

Answer (score 2):

As the link you gave is an application under the `MIT˘ licence, you are allowed to change the application. in [ExceptionHandler.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/source/browse/src/com/nullwire/trace/ExceptionHandler.java).submitStackTraces() is the code which sends the stacktrace. Edit this so that the information is send with an Intent for mail, which is possible.

Comment: Do note, multiple stacktraces can be send, so multiple mail instances will show up.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen other examples but i'm not looking to alter anything if there is a common tool out there. I rather use something I don't have to maintain and is familiar to users.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is to use

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
```

In your main activitys onCreate. This will catch all exceptions not handled by a try catch block. I also recommed sending an lightweight error-report to your server with the stacktrace. This way you can aggregate all crashreports and fastly see where your code is buggy. You will get almost all force-closed reported. I dont think using email is a good idea, as 100 of emails are not so easy to handle, count etc... also Its abit "raping" your user, since he never have asked for sending any emails, He does not even have a clue what its about, unless he is a java developer...

So, don't bother the user with error-reports if you can avoid it.